# Is it possible to have a reverse proxy and forward proxy running on the same interface?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm wondering if it's possible (using any widely available proxy software like mod_proxy, pound, or squid) to have a reverse proxy for incoming connections on an interface and a forward proxy for outgoing connections on the same interface.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible. Why wouldn't it be?

They won't be able to listen on the same IP:Port pair of course, but that is easily remedied.

Comment: Re: edit. Yeah that was my thought. There's no way to have them both running off of say 1.2.3.4:80 right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Seeing as the "routing" by the proxy is done at a pretty high level, could proxy software not just figure out what to do with the request given an HTTP header?